# How does online image editing work?

Tags: image, image-processing

Recently, i was allotted for a project on online photo processing of images. I am a newbie to web designing , so any suggestion or links on how to deploy image editing scripts on web and and use them to edit images.?

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look at this: http://www.ajax-image-editor.com/

I used it a few times and it's pretty powerful and open source.

Comment: sorry, but i am not asking for editing, i am asking how to deploy it

Comment: sorry, but I don't get it.. I think most image editing scripts are self-explanatory. Use its interface. Edit: You can also download the script and use it on your own server (or just have a look at how it works)

Comment: Well, I think the most common way is to use Ajax to give the user the possibility to do dynamic stuff (like dragging etc.) and then pass the data to an image processing PHP script (f.e. by using ImageMagick). As I said, if Ajax Image Editor is kinda what you want, download the code here: http://www.ajax-image-editor.com/ and check it out.

Comment: ok, thanks..and can you point to a link for tutorial of this kind, i searched, but did'nt get good results

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/ajaximageeditor/downloads/list
you can use this php script.
here is the demo : http://pjf-imageeditor.appspot.com/